# Git Branch is still seen after merging and deleting branches under remote branch list

Tags: git, github

I'm working on an automation suite, where I have created two branches "p2pOnOff" and "release" branches.

Later I have merged them to master and deleted them using below commands

```
git branch -d p2pOnOff
git push origin :p2pOnOff
```

I see that these branches are no more seen in github.com

I'm not able to figure out why I still see them listed as remote branches on my computer

```
$ git branch --remote
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  origin/p2pOnOff
  origin/release
```

If I try to prune/delete it, I'm getting below error:

```
$ git remote prune remotes/origin/p2pOnOff
fatal: 'remotes/origin/p2pOnOff' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I missing here? How to get rid of them? I have already tried `git fetch` and `git remote update`, they didn't help !!

I know, deleting entire folder and cloning it again does the job.. But I'm eager to know if there is any other solution??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
git fetch --prune origin
```

it works for me in your case.

From the `git fetch` man-page:

```
-p, --prune
After fetching, remove any remote-tracking branches which no longer exist on the remote.
```

To delete refs on remotes you can also use `git push --delete` which does prune the local reference.

Comment: Worked like charm.. Thanks !!